# Family of functions generating topology on compactly generated space

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a compactly generated Hausdorff space, that is, a set $F\subset X$ is closed if and only if the intersection of $F$ with every compact set is closed.

Further let $\mathcal F$ be a family of continuous functions separating points from compact sets, that is, such that for every $x\in X$ and every compact $K$ there exists $f\in\mathcal F$ and $a=a_{x,K}>0$ with $f(x)=0$ and $f\geq a$ on $K$.

**Question:** Is it true that $\mathcal F$ generates $\tau$?

**Comments:**

1. The statement above is supposed to mimick the analogous one for closed sets (in place of compact sets):

> If $\mathcal F$ is a family of continuous functions separating points from closed sets, then $\mathcal F$ generates $\tau$

a proof of which can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2275664/a-family-such-that-separates-points-of-closed-sets).

2. The reason for assuming Hausdorffness is that (otherwise) there are many (in)equivalent definitions of compactly generated topological space (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1159006/how-to-define-a-compactly-generated-space)).
3. If necessary, I am happy to assume that $(X,\tau)$ is  completely regular, so that $\mathcal F$ is known *a priori* to be generated by the family of all continuous functions.

Comment: How about taking $X$ to be an infinite discrete space? According to your requirements we can let $\mathcal{F}$ be the collection of characteristic functions of finite subsets of $X$. The topology this family generate is not even Hausdorff.

Comment: @Tyrone indeed that's a very good point, thank you. I would be interested in sufficient conditions for the statement to be true, but you could post your comment as a negative answer if you like.